# What is the concept of user in Docker and how does permission work in volume?

Tags: docker

I can't understand the concept of user in Docker.

These are my questions:

1. Does each Docker container have its own users and groups or Docker containers use the host user management?
2. What is the `--user` parameter that we pass to the `docker run` command?
3. Is it possible for Docker container or Docker daemon to create user on host OS?
4. How does the ownership and file permission work in Docker volume?

For the 4th question imagine I have the following volume:

```
--volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

And the result of the `ls` and `id` commands in host OS are as follow:

```
root@tashkhisi:/var/run# ls -l docker.sock
srw------- 1 root docker 0 Jul 30 18:44 docker.sock

root@novinhost:/var/run# id -u  root
0
```

Does it mean I can only access that file from within Docker container with user whose id is 0 inside Docker container?
I mean container see that file with original file permissions but with its own users?

Please, don't notice the `/var/run/docker.sock` file I just want to know how permission works.
I just used it because it is a common use case.

Comment: Check out https://medium.com/@mccode/understanding-how-uid-and-gid-work-in-docker-containers-c37a01d01cf

Answer (score 12):

Yes, each container has its own set of users. If you look at the user IDs inside the container, you will find very large numbers (which is completely fine in Linux), which are individually created. Dockerd has a range of UIDs which it uses for that.

The `--user` option is just a shortcut for running `su`; it switches from the default of `root` to another user for the invocation of the first command inside the container.

You cannot normally create host users from inside the container (unless you hack your way out of the container, or doing weird stuff like mounting the `/etc` of the host into the container... which is probably not what you're asking about); and the daemon (which itself is not containerized, of course) does not do it either.

For your final question: mounting host volumes generally leads to permission issues - if you, for example, create files inside the container, they will end up with the large UIDs on the host side (i.e., the temporary UIDs I mentioned above). In your case, only `root` has access to that file per default. You'll need to `chown` as appropriate. You can run `docker run --user uid:group` and thus override the temporary UIDs/GIDs which dockerd normally creates for you.

But your specific question seems to be about something called "docker in docker" or "dind", where you run docker commands from inside a docker container by mounting the host docker socket into the container. Please google for that or ask more specific questions. There should be plenty of tutorials etc. out there.

Also, a final hint: it is possible to run the docker demon itself as a non-root user. For this I would also reference you to google or the Docker documentation since you're not asking about it so far and things will get quite convoluted if you go that route...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated my question could you please answer the 4th question.

Comment: Thanks, but I just want to know how permission works in docker volume I just used `/var/run/docker.sock` because it is a common use case.

Comment: I beg to differ for your 1st answer @anoe , if you refer https://medium.com/@mccode/understanding-how-uid-and-gid-work-in-docker-containers-c37a01d01cf the host and container both uses the same set of UIDs

Answer (score 7):

> Does each docker container have its own users and groups

Yes.

> docker containers uses the host user management?

No.

> What is the --user parameter that we pass to docker run command?

The documentation for `docker run --user` is short, I wil paraphrase documentation for `Dockerfile USER` command:

> root (id = 0) is the default user within a container. The image
> developer can create additional users. Those users are accessible by
> name.     The developer can choose a user to run the first process
> with the `--user` command line option.

> Is it possible for docker container or docker daemon to create user on host OS?

You can start sshd on your host, login from docker container to host via ssh and do would normally do.

---

The word "user management" is a big word for a linux world. It's simple - list of users and groups is stored in few flles like `/etc/passwd` `/etc/shadow` `/etc/groups`. These are *files* stored in *text* format, no magic. When you add a line to `/etc/passwd` you have a new user. When you remove a line with any text editor from `/etc/passwd`, then you just removed an user. A docker container has separate filesystem, so it has separate `/etc/` directory, so it has separate these files, so it has separate users and groups.

---

> How does the ownership and file permission work in docker volume?

There is no differences. There is no point in explaining here how *unix user-group-other permission model works, refer to endless net resources...

> Does it mean I can only access that file from within docker container with user whose id is 0 inside docker container?

Yes - the permissions are `rw-------`...

> I mean container see that file with original file permissions but with its own users?

Yes.

`--volume` option is just a `mount -o bind`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated my question could you please answer the 4th question.

Answer (score 3):

In general containers do not create *anything* on the host operating system<sup>1</sup>. They boot up, run, and get destroyed while leaving no permanent footprint.

The "user" is entirely within the container, it's in effect just a ID number, same as group. These exist within the confines of the container and have no effect on the host operating system. That is, the `/etc/passwd` file is used to define users and their relative permissions in conjunction with file-system ownership and potentially things like SELinux. It really depends on what your container uses as a base.

Sometimes containers define users with more limited permissions to run services for various reasons, usually security. This is common-place. The `--user` option allows you to run commands as a particular user *as defined in the container itself*.

A super bare-bones container may have only `root` as the user, ID 1. Most have more than that for various historical reasons<sup>2</sup>, but they're not usually used.

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically they do create some artifacts, like an image of the running container, open ports, etc., but nothing like users, groups, or arbitrary files. Not without special permissions, in any case. If you have a container with sufficiently broad privileges it can do whatever it wants.

<sup>2</sup> For example many containers come with the usual repertoire of dusty old relics like `mail`, `ftp`, `games` and sometimes even `uucp` even though none of those actually get used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated my question could you please answer the 4th question.

Comment: File permissions work the same as they always do with the user/group/other settings being applied vs. the UID/GID of the process(es).

Comment: That was UID of the user not process.

Comment: @tashkhisi Without a running process a "user" is just a line in the `/etc/passwd` file.

Answer (score 1):

Please find below the answers.

- Does each docker container have its own users and groups or docker containers uses the host user management?

  > When building the docker image then we have to specify the User to be created for use in the
  > container. By default everything is created with root user.
- What is the `--user` parameter that we pass to `docker run` command?

  > When running the container in docker we can specify the user to start the container with by user `--user`. The container will only start
  > if the same user was created during the docker image build or else it
  > will fail to start container.
- Is it possible for docker container or docker daemon to create user on host OS?

  > Docker daemon creates the docker container on the host OS but each container has its
  > own Kernel thus it cant create a user in the host OS.

You can get more details in this article: [Understanding how uid and gid work in Docker containers | by Marc Campbell | Medium](https://medium.com/@mccode/understanding-how-uid-and-gid-work-in-docker-containers-c37a01d01cf).

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through all the answers and I see that almost all of them fail to answer the first question correctly.

> Does each Docker container have its own users and groups or Docker
> containers use the host user management?

The users and groups inside docker containers and host machine are the same

You can find more info about this in the below links -

https://medium.com/@mccode/understanding-how-uid-and-gid-work-in-docker-containers-c37a01d01cf

https://suraj.io/post/root-in-container-root-on-host/